# NullReferenceException in SharpSvn's SvnClient when the supplied DefaultCredentials returns null

Tags: c#, .net, svn, sharpsvn

I'm using SharpSvn in my project to communicate with SVN. For some SVN repostories, I already know the user name and password, while for others, I don't. Thus, I set the `SvnClient.Authentication.DefaultCredentials` property to an instance of my own implementation of `System.Net.ICredentials` (pseudo code):

```
public class MyCredentials : ICredentials
{
    public NetworkCredential GetCredential(Uri uri, string authType)
    {
        if (AreCredentialsKnown(uri))
            return new NetworkCredential("KnownUserName", "KnownPassword");
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

This works fine for known credentials. However, if the credentials are not known, a `NullReferenceException` occurs in SharpSvn:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Net.NetworkCredential.InternalGetUserName()
   at System.Net.NetworkCredential.get_UserName()
   at SharpSvn.Implementation.SvnCredentialWrapper.OnUserNamePassword(Object sender, SvnUserNamePasswordEventArgs e) in f:\qqn\sharpsvn-dist-1.6\src\sharpsvn\svnauthentication.h:line 619
```

This is apparently caused by the fact that I return `null` from the GetCredential method. However, as is clearly stated by [the MSDN documentation on the ICredentials interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.icredentials.aspx):

> The **GetCredential** method returns a NetworkCredential instance that contains the credentials that are associated with the specified URI and authorization scheme. When no credentials are available, the **GetCredential** method returns **null**.

Is this a bug in SharpSvn? Otherwise, what am I supposed to return when the credentials are not known?

**Edit:** I just discovered that I can return `new NetworkCredentials()` instead of `null` to indicate to SharpSvn that the credentials are unknown. Still, I think this is a bug in SharpSvn as returning `null` should work equally well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .DefaultCredentials is only an alternative for providing one explicit username and password to the Subversion libraries.

If you need a more advanced prompting mechanism you should hook the .UserNamePassword event on SvnClient.Autorization. This also allows managing if passwords should be saved, etc.

There is a default implementation in SharpSvn.UI.dll which hooks some standard dialogs.